# Migrating a Bazaar repo to Git: path not in branch error

Tags: git, bazaar, git-fast-import

I am trying to convert [this](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Eonboard/onboard/trunk) Bazaar repo to Git.

```
bzr branch lp:onboard
cd onboard
git init
bzr fast-export --plain . | git fast-import
```

But I get this error:

```
22:10:43 Calculating the revisions to include ...
22:10:43 Starting export of 2952 revisions ...
22:10:43 1000/2952 commits exported at 448681/minute 
...
22:10:43 1000/2952 commits exported at 239415/minute 
fatal: Path onboard/copying not in branch
fast-import: dumping crash report to .git/fast_import_crash_3847
brz: broken pipe
```

[fast_import_crash_3847](https://gist.github.com/AlexP11223/0a3b808c1130b97919680d3f86972c42)

Tried `bzr` and `Breezy`, two different OS (Arch Linux and Ubuntu).

Comment: It seems like there is a problem with the file path in the Bazaar repository. To fix the issue, you can use *bzr fast-export* with the *--export-marks* and *--import-marks* options. These options help manage the relationship between Bazaar and Git revisions while converting the repository. Follow these steps: First, install the bzr-fastimport plugin if you haven't already. You can install it using: pip install bzr-fastimport Create a new directory for the Git repository and initialize it: mkdir onboard_git cd onboard_git git init Run bzr fast-export with --export-marks and --import-marks optio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of fast-export, you can also use Breezy's native support for pushing to Git:

```
% bzr branch https://code.launchpad.net/onboard onboard-bzr
Branched 2295 revisions.
% git init onboard-git
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/onboard-git/.git/
% cd onboard-bzr
% bzr push --lossy ../onboard-git
Pushing from a Bazaar to a Git repository. For better performance, push into a Bazaar repository.
All changes applied successfully.
Pushed up to revision 2295.
15 tags updated.
% cd ..
% diff -ur onboard-bzr onboard-git
Only in onboard-bzr: .bzr
Only in onboard.git: .git
```

Comment: Seems to work. I guess it should be a more reliable solution than figuring out how to fix fast-export.

Answer (score 4):

That is a bug in the `fast-export` functionality of `bzr`.

In revision 1 the directories `python-virtkey-0.3/` and `sok-0.23/` were added, among other things including the file `sok-0.23/copying`.
In revision 2 `python-virtkey-0.3/` was renamed to `python-virtkey/` and `sok-0.23/` to `onboard/` and thus `sok-0.23/copying` to `onboard/copying`.
In revision 56 then `onboard/copying` was renamed to `COPYING`.

The problem is, that `fast-export` emits only this for revision 2:

```
commit refs/heads/master
mark :2
committer Henrik Nilsen Omma <henrik@ubuntu.com> 1155815101 +0100
data 18
rename and cleanup
from :1
D python-virtkey_0.3.dsc
D python-virtkey_0.3_i386.changes
D sok_0.23.dsc
D sok_0.23_i386.changes
```

It misses to iterate the renamed directory and emit renamings for each individual file in them.

To work-around the problem, you would need to find all such directory renames in the repo history and fix the fast-input stream accordingly. If you do so, be aware that the fast-import format also contains binary data, so you might not be able to do this with a text editor without breaking the binary files.

If you check with `bzr log -v | grep '/ =>'` you see that there were 14 directory renamings and you would need to manually fix all of them to work-around the issue.

Even if you do not get an error message, the result might be wrong without fixing it, as then the renamings are not done and if a file then would have been edited after the rename, the first commit actually creates it while the old file still remains present and so on.

So the best way is probably to report the bug if not already done and wait for a proper fix, and then closely investigate the conversion result to make sure there are not more such issues that maybe do not result in a failure but just in a wrong result.

The bug should be this one: https://bugs.launchpad.net/brz/+bug/1890216
with a fix already available at: [https://code.launchpad.net/~cjwatson/brz/fastimport-fix-directory-renames/+merge/410767](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Ecjwatson/brz/fastimport-fix-directory-renames/+merge/410767)
since 1.5 years, but noone seems to bother integrating it.

Comment: FWIW It's not actually confirmed that that is a fix for this bug, nor that it is actually correct and doesn't break anything else.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I just concluded from the written text of the issue and the pull request that it is the same issue and would fix it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue either when or after brz was exporting revisions:

```
$ brz fast-export | git fast-import                                                                             fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
15:27:48 Calculating the revisions to include ...
15:27:48 Starting export of 237 revisions ...
brz: broken pipe
```

The workaround for me was to export to a file, create the git repo and import.

```
brz fast-export > brz-export
git init .
cat brz-export | git fast-import
```